# Conditionally render .hbs templates emberjs

Tags: html, ember.js, conditional-statements, render, yeoman

EDIT:

I would like to conditionally display templates inside of a larger template as long as the presence of the larger template is True.

in sidebar.hbs

```
<div id="sidebar-wrapper" class="super-super-float-right-col">
  <div id="sidebar-wrapper" class="super-float-right-col">
    <div id="sidebar-wrapper" class="float-right-col">
      {{#if permit.id}}
          {{render 'applicant'}}
          {{render 'location'}}
      {{else}}
       <h2>Nope!</h2>  
      {{/if}}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In application.hbs I call the sidebar and the outlet

```
{{render sidebar}}
{{outlet}}
```

So technically the sidebar is currently unrelated to the results of the `{{outlet}}`.

I want to connect the the results of the `{{outlet}}` with which templates are rendered in sidebar.hbs.

Right now I'm getting "Nope!"

EDIT: I was able to use `{{#if this.id}}` to make the conditions on the `permit.hbs` page true. Now I'm trying to figure out how to apply that same logic for rendering

Much love,
Ian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're in the permit template there is no point in checking if you're in the template.  That's analogous to saying if true, because the only reason that code would be executing would be because it's there executing it.

If that wasn't exactly what you meant update your question.

If you want something in your template to change based on the route, the application controller has a property called currentPath which has the current application path, you can watch it and create computed properties that change based on the current path.

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/iCIkEsib/2/edit

Comment: If permit is already true, then why would I get the {{else}}?

Comment: @IanSteffy Are you sure that `permit` is true. The best way to know is put a {{permit}} in your template to see the output value

Comment: {{permit}} yields no noticeable difference to the permit.hbs template

Comment: no, I'm saying that permit isn't a real thing, but there is no point in checking to see if you are in the permit template, when you are in the permit template.  It's analogous to getting in your car then asking the question, am I in my car?  The permit template won't be executed (rendered) unless you are in the permit template.

Comment: I've updated the question. What if I want to check that my friend is in my car so I can enter the car from a different door? How do I set a conditional based on a specific route?

Comment: okay, so are you saying, you want your outer template to render something different based on which route it's in?

Comment: yes! :) The outlet for the main content and the render for the sidebar are both in the application.hbs and I want them to render the content depending on where we are in the route. Ex. "/permit/#/" will render the permit information in both the permit.hbs and the sidebar.