# Using Conditionals to Render templates pending on which Parent Template we are in

Tags: templates, ember.js, conditional-statements, render, routes

I would like to conditionally display templates inside of a larger template as long as the presence of the larger template is True.

in sidebar.hbs

```
<div id="sidebar-wrapper" class="super-super-float-right-col">
  <div id="sidebar-wrapper" class="super-float-right-col">
    <div id="sidebar-wrapper" class="float-right-col">
      {{#if permit.id}}
          {{render 'applicant'}}
          {{render 'location'}}
      {{else}}
       <h2>Nope!</h2>  
      {{/if}}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In application.hbs I call the sidebar and the outlet

{{render sidebar}} {{outlet}}

So technically the sidebar is currently unrelated to the results of the {{outlet}}.

I want to connect the the results of the {{outlet}} with which templates are rendered in sidebar.hbs.

Right now I'm getting "Nope!"

EDIT: I was able to use {{#if this.id}} to make the conditions on the permit.hbs page true. Now I'm trying to figure out how to apply that same logic for rendering

Much love, Ian

Comment: possible duplicate of [Conditionally render .hbs templates emberjs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20354965/conditionally-render-hbs-templates-emberjs)

Comment: I thought that since I completely reworded the entire Question into a new question that it deserved a new topic. I did not, however, want to delete the information of the previous question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the application.hbs you have the properties from your ApplicationController. So in the ApplicationController you should do the logic for wether displaying the sidebar or not.

Comment: What kind of logic would that be?

Comment: You can set a property in your application controller that is accessible from your application.hbs. All properties in sidebar.hbs access only the SidebarController properties. Maybe you can setup a js bin with more code?